# Split every array element and transform to multiple dimenssion array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array POST after submited the form:

```
$POST = Array
(
    [29#487_Mon] => 90,
    [29#487_Mon_power] => 50,
    [30#487_Thur]=>80,
    [30#487_Thur_power]=>90,
    [41#487_Wed]=>10,
    [41#487_Wed_power]=>20,

)
```

And I want is transform the $POST array to more friendly format that look like this:

```
$Transform = array(
    [29]=>array(
            [487_Mon] => 90,
            [487_Mon_power] => 50
            ),
    [30]=>array(
            [487_Thur]=>80,
            [487_Thur_power]=>90
            ),
    [41]=>array(
            [487_Wed]=>10,
            [487_Wed_power]=>20
            )
    )
```

Anyone Know how to do this?

Comment: change your form to use array notation, e.g. name="29[487_Mon]" and it will be that way automatically

Comment: @Gordonit does not works! are you sure just format the name of form elements ?

Comment: IIRC numeric indexes in `$_POST` don't work or can cause problems. That could be avoided with names like `"transform[29][487_Mon]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expanding on what @Gordon said. If @Gordon wishes to submit his comment as an answer, I will retract my answer.

Tested and works

```
<?
    if( $_POST['submit'] ) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r( $_POST );
        echo "</pre>";
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="29[487_Mon]"/>
    <input type="text" name="29[487_Mon_power]"/>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="30[487_Thur]"/>
    <input type="text" name="30[487_Thur_power]"/>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="41[487_Wed]"/>
    <input type="text" name="41[487_Wed_power]"/>
    <br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by @Gordon in the comment, additionally, you can do it by:

```
<?php
$Transform = array();
foreach($POST as $key => $val){
 $key_parts = explode("#", $key); //spliting 29#487_Mon to 29 and 487_Mon
 /*
 $key_parts[0] = 29
 $key_parts[1] = 487_Mon
 */
 $Transform[$key_parts[0]][$key_parts[1]] = $val;
}
echo  '<pre>';
print_r($Transform);
echo  '</pre>';
?>
```

See [Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/g73-6jq)

Comment: You can also use `list` function i.e. `list($part1, $part2) = explode("#", $key, 2)`.